# Where can I find GitHub's key id to import key for github_repository_deploy_key resource?

Tags: terraform, github

I've added GitHub Deploy key manually. Now I would likt to `import` it to my state. But when I look into [github_repository_deploy_key resource docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository_deploy_key#import) I can read

> *"Repository deploy keys can be imported using a colon-separated pair of repository name and GitHub's key id. The latter can be obtained by GitHub's SDKs and API."*
>
> *`$ terraform import github_repository_deploy_key.foo test-repo:23824728`*

I was looking for this GitHub's key id for a long time but without a luck. If I go to [https://github.com/\](https://github.com/%5C)/<REPO>/settings/keys I cannot see any ID (numerical) in my key information.

I've try to use `SHA256:` bit from deploy key information, but it end's up with the following error:

> Error: Unexpected ID format ("ddf62fc..."), expected numerical ID. strconv.ParseInt: parsing "ddf62fc...": invalid syntax

How can I find my GitHub's (deploy) key ID?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it..

```
gh api https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/keys | jq .[].id
```